# Remove Paint brush through python

Tags: python, scripting

Can texture paint brushes be removed through Python ? I wanted to remove a brush of a specific name for example "Brush57". Removing it by shift clicking the x button usually sets it's user to 0 so it still remains in the memory. How am i to remove the brush from the memory/datablock ?

Answer (score 2):

The brushes collection is available thru [`bpy.data.brushes`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendData.html?bpy.types.BlendData.brushes#bpy.types.BlendData.brushes)  Like most (maybe all) ID object collections in blender, items can be removed with [`collection.remove(obj)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendDataBrushes.html#bpy.types.BlendDataBrushes.remove).

```
import bpy
# get the brush
brush = bpy.data.brushes.get("Brush67")

# if brush is None well make a new one for example

if brush is None:
    brush = bpy.data.brushes.new("Brush67")

# remove the brush

bpy.data.brushes.remove(brush)
```

Comment: I see it worked but I wasn't clear in my question, I have edited it. Removing it usually sets the user of the brush in the data block to 0 so it still stays in the memory, I was asking how to remove it completely from the memory through Python.